# Lambda Expression - Error Cannot implicitly convert type `vicoapi.Pictures' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<vicoapi.Pictures>' (CS0029)

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, generics, lambda, asp.net-core

Hello Together following my Code:

```
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<VicoTvEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(VicoTvEntities context)
    {
        var pictures = new List<Pictures>{
            new Pictures { Name = "Testbild", Url="localhost/test" }
        };
        var user = new List<User>{
            new User{Username="Muster", Password="Pass",Email="max.muster@mustermail.com",Bio="Musterbiografie", Pictures = pictures.Find(pic => pic.Name == "Testbild")}
        };
    }
}
```

}

I try to build an API and at the moment, I work on the connection of the DB to the code. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

My Problem is, whenever I try to add the Picture it won't work, because of this converting error. How can I avoid this problem and implement the picture to the User.
My Source Tree looks like this:
[Source Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKl4B.png)

The User Class looks as following:

```
public class User
{
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public List<Pictures> Pictures { get; set; }
    public List<Follow> Following { get; set; }
    public List<Follow> Followed { get; set; }
}
```

The Error I get looks like this:

> /Users/username/vicotv-Backend/vicoapi/vicoapi/Models/SampleData.cs(126,126): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `vicoapi.Pictures'to   System.Collections.Generic.List' (CS0029) (vicoapi)

Comment: Show definition of `User` class. You question is unclear in its current format

Comment: @Nkosi now I've add the class.

Comment: Then the already provided answer addresses the problem. List.Find returns a single instance which you are trying to assign to a List. What was the intention? Do you want a collection or single object

Comment: @Nkosi Now I have updated it, and change it to public Pictures Pictures {get; set;} because it should only one picture per profile. 
This was a mistake from my side. I just want a single object, but as you can see in the other answer it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you, now it works, after I write this comment, i realized, that I should rename Pictures to Picture. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't show the class here, I'm fairly certain that your User class has a property defined something like this:

```
public List<Pictures> Pictures { get; set; }
```

If that is the case, you need to assign the property to the whole list like this:

```
user.Pictures = pictures
```

If you want a user to only be able to have one picture then you need to define the Picture property on the User class like this:

```
public Pictures Picture { get; set; }
```

If you define the Picture property like this it should work with your current code.

P.S. I would definitely recommend renaming your "Pictures" class to "Picture". In general you should use the singular form for class names. Have a look [at this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/classes-naming-singular-or-plural) for more information.

Comment: now I have updated my Picture Class and did it like you proposed (public Pictures Picture {get; set;}).
Wehen I try to add user.Picture another error shows up. 
I have the same error and now i have add the Class, how it was initial. But now i did it, like you proposed.

Comment: Edit: Now it works, i've made a small mistake, i forgot to delete the s in Picture. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.